# Merge debug information from several elf files

Tags: debugging, debug-symbols, keil

I have to debug using Keil Microvision a complex system involving several elf files each containing it's own debug information. This appears to be a bug in the Keil debugger but subsequent loading .axf-files containing debug information using  the "load" keyword with "incremental" option increases the overall load time nearly exponentially with each new file added to the initial debugger script. The load of the 10mb .axf file containing 8,5mb of debug data takes acceptable time of less than a minute. Adding a just 1MB .axf-file with 800k debug info lets the time grow by 2,5 additional minutes. Adding the third file increases the load time to 8 minutes for 15MB of data in total. I don't want to waste my time analyzing yet another bug in the Keil software but I'm looking for the solution which could be e.g. merging of the debug information from several .axf into one. I know how to merge e.g. stripped debug information with a bin file with eu_unstrip or how to remove or extract the debug info with objcopy etc. But I'm stuck looking for the way to merge the debug information from several .axf (elf) files into one.

May be some additional Information. I'm using the most current version of Keil and changing the order, e.g. small files first doesn't solve the problem.